# Diagrams of links in public domain or licensed under Creative Commons

Tags: knot-theory, online-resources

I'm writing a set of notes on topology that I'd like to share under the Creative Commons. Does anyone know where to find diagrams for links (not the Borromean link, I have that already) that are either in the **Public Domain** or under a **Creative Commons** license? It's for the knot theory section.

Most images from the Wikimedia Commons are either in the Public Domain or are licensed under the Creative Commons [Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

The links should preferably have many components, be "asymmetric", and hopefully most of their components can be knotted as well. A table of such links would be great but I'd be grateful for even one! The only "freely licensed" images I can find are of very simple links.

**Edit:**

In the end I gave up and made my own link drawing by editing together different knots. But still I think the original question has merit.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about what "freely licensed" necessarily entails, but LinkInfo is quite a good table as far as links go.

http://www.indiana.edu/~linkinfo/

It is run by Charles Livingston and Jae Choon Cha. I imagine that as long as you cited where you got the images from it would be fine.

Comment: Sorry, by "freely licensed" I meant in the Public Domain or with a Creative Commons license. I clarified that in my question.